# MotionEvent coordinates to Scene coordinates

Tags: touch, andengine, multi-touch

I am developing an application using multi-touch in AndEngine. To get the coordinates of touching fingers I use `pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getX([pointer index])` because TouchEvent doesn't have an equivalent getter, only `pSceneTouchEvent.getX()`.

The problem is that MotionEvent returns coordinates on the screen while TouchEvent returns coordinates on the Scene. When I zoom in or out, the screen and Scene coordinates do not match, so I need to convert the screen coordinates to Scene coordinates. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. Andengine handles touch events in a different way to Android so there is no history of touch coordinates. I simply store them myself in private variables before handling the event:

```
if (pSceneTouchEvent.getPointerID() == 0) {
    pointer0LastX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
    pointer0LastY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
}
if (pSceneTouchEvent.getPointerID() == 1) {
    pointer1LastX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
    pointer1LastY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
}
```

Then I just access these instead of getting the values from the TouchEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem and have a solution. First I want to explain it and then will paste the convert method.

**The problem**

Coordinates you want to have is *scene coordinates* which are related to your scene start point (0,0) (i.e. AndEngine anchorCenter is bottom-left). Bounds: from (0,0) to [Camera.getSurfaceWidth(), Camera.getSurfaceHeight()].

Coordinates you've got from MotionEvent is *screen coordinates* with bounds from (0,0) to [displayMetrix.widthPixels, displayMetrix.heightPixels] and they're independat of zoom or camera-to-scene-position.

**Solution explanation**

For the *abscissa* (in general *x*) you must translate *screen corrdinates* to relevant *scene coordinates* (bounded with camera width) and sum the up to the camera left corner position (on the scene). In formula it looks like:

```
x = cameraStartX + screenX * camera.width / display.width

cameraStartX - the camera left corner x position on the scene
screenX - x you get from MotionEvent
camera.width - just getWidth() from your camera method
display.width - display width from DisplayMetrics
```

For the *ordinate* (in general *y*) you have to do the same as for the abscissa but remember that it has a different direction. So the formula will be a bit changed:

```
y = cameraStartY+(display.heigth-screenY)*camera.height/display.heigth

cameraStartY - camera left corner y position on the scene
screenX - y you get from MotionEvent
camera.height - just getHeight() from your camera method
display.height - display height from DisplayMetrics
```

**The method implementation example**

```
public static void convertScreenToSurfaceCoordinates(
        final Camera camera,
        final Context context,
        final float[] screenCoordinates,
        final float[] surfaceCoordinates) {
    //you may want to have a separate methods and fields for display metrics
    //and no Context as a method param
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    float displayWidth = Math.max(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
    loat displayHeight = Math.min(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels); 

    //abscissa
    surfaceCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = camera.getXMin()
            + screenCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X] * camera.getWidth()
            / displayWidth;
    //ordinate
    surfaceCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = camera.getYMin()
            + (displayHeight - screenCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y])
            * camera.getHeight() / displayHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the original MotionEvent from the TouchEvent.

Comment: I did that, see the question. The problem was that the coordinates specified the touched point on the phone screen, not the Scene. TouchEvent translates the screen coordinates to Scene coordinates, I was looking for a method that would do that for me.